# Trying find how to cancel TabControl.SelectionChanged in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, tabcontrol

I am trying figure out how cancel this event in Silverlight, sadly I didn't find any useful link with the solution. (I saw some post for wpf which I think are not longer available for Silverlight)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the bare bones of it:-

```
    bool cancellingTabSelectionChange = false;
    private void tabControl1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && !cancellingTabSelectionChange)
        {
            cancellingTabSelectionChange = true;
            ((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
            cancellingTabSelectionChange = false;
        }
    }
```

You would need to add the extra criteria the would allow a change to take place since the above code would always block a change of tab.

Answer (score 0):

As i know there is not straight way to cancel it. You can disable control if dont want change tab, or set selectedtab to which you want after selectionchanged fired.

```
 private void tabControl1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = [index of tab]
    }
```