# How to make Tabcontrol popup a message before TabItem changed

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabcontrol, tabitem, selectionchanged

I ma under a situation where i use Selectionchanged event of TabControl on changing TabItem.

I do something like this:

```
tabcntrl.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler( obj.TabControl_SelectionChanged);
public void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("check1");
}
```

What i want is when i click the tab to be changed then before opening tab it should print this messageBox and "it do nicely with the code i have written" .
But when i change this code to this: (Its my coustom button made from childwindow)

```
tabcntrl.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler( obj.TabControl_SelectionChanged);
 public void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           string msg = "Tab Changed :Save data of MetaviewModel ?";
           CoustomButtonMessage cusButton = new CoustomButtonMessage("Error", msg, MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           cusButton.Show();
        }
```

This code on changing the tab first
: Switch to another tab then it pop ups this messagebox whereas in previous code it was first popuping up meassgebox and then switching to another 
tab.And what i want is to make the second code work like the first one.

I mean it should first popup messagebox of second code and then it should switch to another tab not before. **(It is because this pop up will again decide rather to save data of current tab or not bnefore going to next tab)**

```
How to acheieve this ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ChildWindow.Show() seems to be semi-modal, meaning it returns immediately, however when the window is actually opened it behaves as a modal window - that is everything in the background is dimmed.
To workaround this, you have to subscribe to the Closed event of the ChildWindow and perform your custom actions only when this event is fired.

Here, let me show you how to do this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ChildWindow w = new ChildWindow();
    ShowChildWindowAndPerformAction(w,
        () =>
        {
            //put your custom code here that needs to be run when the window is closed
            int i = 5;
        });
}

public void ShowChildWindowAndPerformAction(ChildWindow w, Action action)
{
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (sender2, args2) =>
    {
        w.Closed -= handler;

        action();
    };

    w.Closed += handler;

    w.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know that my purpose is when i chnage the tab then on clicking the next tab it must popup messagebox to know if i want to save current data(keeping the control in the current tab yet). When i click"yes" then saving it otherwise switching to next tab.

Comment: @Tanish i done the same but it still do the same. When i click on the another tab it first switch to that Tab and then it pop ups the Window.

Comment: Unfortunately, TabControl does not expose a cancellable event like SelectionChanging, so you have to do this the hard way, refer to [Other StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915432/trying-find-how-to-cancel-tabcontrol-selectionchanged-in-silverlight).

Comment: @Tanish thanks but could you please bit explain a more in detail? i am not able to understand yet

Comment: Unfortunately, TabControl does not expose a cancellable event like SelectionChanging, so you have to do this the hard way, refer to another stackoverflow question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915432/trying-find-how-to-cancel-tabcontrol-selectionchanged-in-silverlight).

Comment: As for the Action parameter, consider it as the code fragment that should run when you click on Yes.
In your own CustomButtonMessage implementation, you should set the ChildWindow's DialogResult property to true if the user presses Yes, and to false in all other cases.

Then you can extend ShowChildWindowAndPerformAction() to only execute the provided action parameter if w.DialogResult evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to show the messagebox in async way with low thread priority,

```
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>MessageBox.Show("Test"), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```